# Webview на разных версиях Андроид

Tags: android, android-webview

Проблема следующая: есть WebView приложение, которое на разных версиях Android ведет себя по разному. Сразу оговорюсь камнями не кидайте, я не очень грамотен в java и вообще в программировании под Android. Но по урокам из интернета собрал вполне работающее приложение, которое отлично работает и протестировано на нескольких устройствах одно из них на android 4.4 другое на андроид 5.1, по отзывам пользователей на android 7.0 тоже все работает прилично, но у людей с Android 6.0 возникает проблема с кнопкой назад - приложение закрывается, на остальных версиях кнопка прыгает по History API, при этом планшеты на 6.0 перемещаются по history, но при возврате экран перемещается вверх страниц хотя в javascript сайта указано if('scrollRestoration' in history){history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';} в противном случае запоминать позицию скрола и перемещать туда куда надо.

ПОЧЕМУ?

Такое ощущение что компонент WebView не вшивается в приложение, а использует системный и на всех версиях он разный, может быть он еще и зависит от какой браузер используется о умолчанию?

Есть ли возможность как то это обойти чтобы не сходить с ума от кроссвебвьюерности?

Comment: а android 6 - это не samsung был? Они используют свой собственный браузер. Есть способы его залочить, указать на дефолтный с google service. Но если у вас на всех 6-ых проблема, тут я Вам не посоветую

Comment: history.scrollRestoration = 'manual'; - не работает на ZTE BLADE не помню точно какой. 
С History на вылет вообще сам проверял на Vertex а по отзывам Это самсунг J1 на 6.0. у меня есть (J1 на 5.1 проблем нет) и MI 4LTE (cancro) - тоже на  6.0

Comment: MI 4LTE (cancro) тоже не работает? или тоже работает?

Comment: вот отзыв по MI 4LTE "Не работает кнопка назад, когда выхожу из чтения статьи совсем выхожу из 
приложения, а на планшете возвращаюсь к первой статье в списке"

Comment: Начиная с Android 5.0 webview вынесен в отдельный компонент и может обновляться из маркета: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=ru - если почитать комменты, то становится ясно, что большинство юзеров уверены что это ненужная хрень, удаляют и отключают обновления. Поинтересуйтесь какая на проблемных аппаратах версия этого приложения и порекомендуйте обновить. И желательно выяснить полную картину происшествия: всегда/иногда, при каких действиях воспроизводятся проблемы и логи собирать не плохо бы при этом.

Comment: Да я написал логирования ошибок javascript у пользователей и заметил что на этих устройствах не работает history. Т.е. не отрабатывает history.push из за чего кнопка назад пытаясь вернуться по стеку возврата находит его пустым и вываливается из приложения. Но в логах я могу лишь получить версию браузера и модель телефона и не более того. Какая версия компонента стоит на устройстве мне не известно. За ссылку спасибо попробую на имеющихся проблемных аппаратах поэкспериментировать. Но заставлять или просить пользователей что то сделать штука конечно не благодарная.